# facebook sharing text, open graph tags

Tags: facebook, graph, tags, sharing

I've asked a couple of questions on here before and got no response so I'm not holding out too much hope, anyway here goes.

I have implemented a facebook sharing button from our site and I'm trying to change the highlighted text in the attached image. Does anyone know how to do this? it's not in any of the documentation and i can't find an og tag for it.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So16C.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: It comes from your App name. That you configure on https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for the info, i'll check it out

Comment: @WizKid Write answers as answers, please, instead of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from your App name. That you configure on developers.facebook.com